# Create list of checked elements

Tags: java, jsf

I am learning Java Beans, JavaServer Faces. And recently I faced to problem. I have dataTable

```
<p:dataTable value="#{someBean.accounts}" var="people">
</p dataTable>
```

In this table there are some rows with information about people. Here I have also column with checkboxes (component: `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`). I may check several checkboxes and select "Delete choosen people" button.

My idea is to create a procedure which will execute on button click, where I will create list of checked people. But here I have issue. How can I add checked people into this list? I have added different ids for checkboxes like `id="check#{people.userID}"`, but I do not know have to operate with web-page ids from bean-class.

Comment: Is there any restriction to use multiple row selection feature of PrimeFaces? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf

Comment: If you're in learning phase, I would suggest you to learn JSF only and not using external libraries as PrimeFaces or RichFaces that might confuse your learning path.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ***isCheck*** variable to your People class.

Then you can try

```
List<People> list= new ArrayList();
for(People item : accounts) {
  if(item.isCheck){
  list.add(item);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, have your accounts custom datatype have a map with boolean variable that maps to that checkbox. On submission simply go through the list and add all rows with that variable set to true to a new list. I use something like this in my current project.

```
<rich:column style="text-align:center;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Declare"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selected" value="#{rBean.selectionMap[selected]}"/>
</rich:column>
```